# $1+px^2$ is a square iff $x\in\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm fairly new to number theory and have just started to study p-adic numbers. In a book I'm reading about the fundamentals of number theory, there is the following statement that is supposed to be easy. However I did not find a proof.

> Let $p \neq 2$ be a prime number, then $1+px^2$ is a square iff $x\in\mathbb Z_p.$

One of my first thoughts was to use the unique representation of $x\in\mathbb Z_p,$ i.e. $x = u p^n,$ where $u\in\mathbb Z_p^\times,\ n\in \mathbb N_0.$

I'd be really glad if someone might hint me into the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p=2$ it is not true, $3$ isn't a square $\bmod 4$.

For $p$ odd and $v_p(x)<0$ then $v_p(1+px^2)=v_p(px^2)$ is odd so $1+px^2$ can't be a square (in $\Bbb{Q}_p$). For $v_p(x)\ge 0$ then $1+px^2$ is a square due to Hensel lemma (or the binomial series).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply! Could you please explain why $v_p(1+px^2) = v_p(px^2)$ and what function to use for the Hensel lemma. Is $f(X)=1-pX^2 -a$ for some $a \in \mathbb Q_p$ correct?

Comment: $v_p(1+x^2)=v_p(px^2)+v_p(1+p^{-1}x^{-2})$. For Hensel lemma: $Y^2-(1+px^2)$. Equivalently $(1+px^2)^{1/2}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {1/2\choose k} (px^2)^k$.